# Wiring assistance for dryer from 4 prong to 3 prong

Tags: electrical, wiring, dryer

Just moved into a new apartment so I had to change my dryer plug.

However, after countless tutorials and videos I am a little confused with the current set-up. Is it right that the green(ground) and the white (neutral) are directly on top of one another? I see the ground screw to the left but nothing is on there...

So my question is when I install my 3 prong how will I ground it? Do I need to buy a ground wire and somehow attach it to the ground screw?

Tried to attach a picture but wouldn't let me because I did not have 10 rep.

Comment: See [my answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/30517/33) to [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30507/where-does-the-ground-wire-go-in-a-3-prong-dryer-cord-configuration). Also note that in a 3 wire configuration, there is no ground wire in the cord.  The cord is instead made up of 2 ungrounded (hot) conductors, and one grounded (neutral) conductor.