# How can I plug my 3 prong dryer into a 4 prong receptacle?

Tags: electrical, wiring, dryer

My dryer blew up  and there is no chance of repair —  it was pretty old anyway. I found a used dryer and brought it home.  Unfortunately, the cord don't match the receptacle. I Need to know if there are adapters for this or is there an easy DIY solution?

[image: the plug and cord]

Answer (score 7):

You'll simply have to purchase a 4 prong dryer cord, which can be found at any local hardware store or big box store.

[image: 4 prong plug]

Then follow the dryer manufacturers installation instructions for connecting a 4 prong plug.
Most dryers will be wired similarly to the one described in [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/30517/33), though it could vary a bit from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Comment: Ok.. I will have to try this! I cant afford an electrician so im hoping I can do this alone.. =) Thank You for your reply!

Comment: I've done this or the inverse several times - it's trivially easy. All you need is a screwdriver.

Comment: The original cable looks like NEMA 10-30, Outlet NEMA 14-30?