# 3 prong to 4 prong dryer cord change

Tags: electrical

My 2 year old whirlpool dryer has a 3 prong cord. My new house has a 4 prong. The dryer doesn't have a spot for 4 wires. The ground wire coming from the dryer is attached to the dryer itself. A new 4 pronged dryer cord has white, red, black, and green wires. Maybe the green wire hooks to the ground screw with the one coming from the dryer?

Comment: Check the manufacturer's documentation, it will tell you how to wire your specific dryer. [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/30517/33) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you can remove the existing grounding wire from the grounding screw, then do that and connect your 4-prong's grounding wire to the screw.

I initially misunderstood your explanation of the existing grounding wire. If this is a wire coming from *inside* the dryer, then you'll likely need to connect it to the neutral lug once you've connected to the grounding screw a suitable ground from your new 4 prong cable. As said in a comment, your best bet is to consult the dryer's manual to verify this is the correct action for this step.